# Lookup a value from entire tab & return top row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

[Reference document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1enejgnQ47cygXBuCD79n2E3eXdqc_FBPZzsn8CVKVtg/edit#gid=2090750202)

Reference tab contains groups listed in row 1, with lists of states underneath each.
The Lookup tab contains states listed in column A.

I am trying to lookup states from column A of the "Lookup" tab on the "Reference" tab and return row 1 (i.e. Group)

I have provided in yellow what the expected outcome should be. I've tried vlookup, index, match, etc to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,tocol(index(if(Reference!A3:G=Σ,Reference!A1:G1,)),1))))
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how this works - but it solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7wXjLR0.png The index part of the formula helps in pulling the respective group header where the state is found and return null values for all the rest. then tocol function just arranges this whole array range into single file by removing blanks.